# Polygon topology validation in ArcGIS - whole study area artefact problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error, topology, validation

I have no experience with topology validation in ArcGIS. I have polygon feature class.

When I create topology for this feature class, I specify two topology rules :

- Must Not Overlap
- Must Not have Gaps

After correcting all understandable artefacts, one problem remained visible on the map.
I would like to ask you if I should to Mark as Exception?

[image]

Comment: Without access to the data, it would be very difficult to determine this. In the Error Inspector, what kind of error does it say this is? And is this picture the full extent of your data?

Comment: Yes the image represents whole my study area. The Error Inspector tool says a "Must Not Have Gaps" rule error. Is there any possibility to share the shapefile in the forum?

Comment: This is all the more strange because the study area was previously clipped out from a larger area ...

Comment: Is the study area itself a polygon in this file? Must Not Have Gaps flags lots of  exceptions such as boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you still have an error at the lower left side of your image, maybe this is the reason why the whole study area is highlighted as red:

[image]

Comment: Yes..., I saw this error directly after I publicated my post. I corrected this artefact. Unfortunately topology still have one error in whole study area....

Answer (score 0):

The outer box will always show as a gap. Once all other errors have been fixed, reassess the topology and verify this is the only remaining error in the error inspector. If the outer box is the only area, then dismiss it and continue with your process.